# How to view source code and project directories of AWS Beanstalk application?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I just launched an AWS beanstalk django application after going through the steps provided by AWS. I used the default settings to create the application (the default "Welcome" page for Django). Is there any way for me to download or view the source code and project directories from the AWS console, or any other location?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sign into AWS Console, click Services in top left, then click Elastic Beanstalk (under Compute), then click on your application (not applicationName-env, but just ApplicationName). Next, click Application Versions on the left hand side and you'll see a list of applications. Under the Source section, you can access the source code of your applcation.

Comment: How to view source code and project directories of AWS Ec2?  can you help please